# How can i hide node of this menu from particular user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a MVC web application and use Telerik panel bar and tree view component and create my own menu .its a panel bar  and tree view that tree view bind to the site map. I want  to this menu for each user show a particular of node for example admin access all nodes and a user with low access just access to particular nodes, that he can see with that user role. I see MvcSiteMapProviderr but i can not get good document for it and i don't know its good for my propose !I think i can create sitemap dynamically by a controller but i don't know how can i do this and is it true ?i have 5 or 6 role in my application .
What is your suggestion for  me which is good? or introduce me a new way if all above are not good thanks.
i have to restrict access to each node of panel bar and tree-view .

[image: this is my menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with MvcSiteMapProvider.

If all you want is to control the visibility, you can build your own [ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider](http://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider).

On the other hand, it sounds more like you are trying to block access to some nodes depending on whether the user has permission. If you are using the AuthorizeAttribute to control access to your controller acctions, you simply need to enable [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider) and you get this for free.